# DataTable : How to make a page load faster?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I have about **20,000** rows in my database, and I use [DataTable](http://www.datatables.net/) to load all of those data.

- DataTable is loading all of my data at the beginning.
- DataTable works fine with a small amount of data like 100 or below, but in my case, my page took about **3** minutes to load a page. Very Bad !

What is the most efficient way to improve the loading speed using **DataTable** ?

---

**Update:**

Here is my table

`<table id="inventory_exact"> ...`

Here is my setting to it

```
  // Setting to Inventory Table 
  $('#inventory_exact').dataTable({

    "lengthMenu": [ 10 ] ,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "searchHighlight": true,
    "bInfo" : false

  });
```

---

**Update 2:** - server side

@niyou : I use PHP Laravel , so I **query** my data and **display** them by doing this

```
            @foreach ( Inventory::all() as $inventory)
             <tr>
                <td>{{ $inventory->sku }} </td>
                <td>{{ $inventory->description }} </td>
                <td>${{ $inventory->price }} </td>
                <td>{{ $inventory->stock }} </td>
             </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Ok... show your code to see what you have tried... Probably using `deferRender: true,` defined will help you =).

Comment: Fine... **First:** I'll encourage you to use [A new DataTables API](https://datatables.net/manual/api). Its " _it presents much greater flexibility and improved functionality._ " and easier to Implement. Just change `$('#inventory_exact').dataTable()` to `$('#inventory_exact').DataTable()` and remove all double quotes. **Second:** Are you using Ajax request? Because you gonna need it if you wanna make your DataTable loading faster...

Comment: @niyou : I've updated my post for your question.

Comment: @bcesars : I tried `deferRender: true` , it seems to take the same amount of time. I use the new API now, thanks for the tip on that. Ajax, I am not sure what Laravel is using behind the scene , I think they might use Ajax call to query data of database.

Comment: Hmmm... In you DataTable snippet has not ajax request. It's really important you use so you can make your DataTable load fast. Including something like this: `ajax: {
   url: "YOUR URL",
   type: 'POST'
  }`, you can call yout server-side script and return with json_encode. DataTables will show your msql data.

Comment: @bcesars : I never use that before, I guess I have a lot of reading that need to do. If I want to query the data out of my database, what is my url:" ? " should be ?

Comment: Also, since I am make a GET request to my database, why the type: ' POST ' ?

Comment: Parameter `url` inside `ajax` option needs to define location of your file which has a query from your database. Parameter `type` can be as `POST` or `GET` request, does no make difference. I'll recommend you to read about [Ajax Objects](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html). There is a simple example on how to use requests Ajax with your serve-side scripts.

Comment: @bcesars : Thank you for your help throughout this post. :D Thanks for your time.

Comment: @iori you're welcome. Actually, its a huge solution and should involve many information from your web-site. So its better direct you to a documentation and process to handle thousands of records in a couple of seconds. =)

Answer (score 2):

When you are dealing with client-side large datasets (by large i define as over 1000) , you would probably want to switch to the Server-side implementation of data for your datatables data

Using the newest 1.10 syntax it would look like this

```
table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
      url:"index.cfm/observers/json",
      },
  });
```

where the url returns a json object that has draw, totalrecordcount, totalfilteredcount, and data

I have included links to documentation for

[Datatables Server-Side Documentation](http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/)

[PHP example script to generate JSON needed for datatables on Github using SSP.class](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php)

[PHP script to generate JSON for datatables written spagetti style (if you cant use SSP or need to use older datatables)](https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_oracle)